# Automated Tests: OIDC: Authorization Code Flow with PKCE: Login credentials

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, automated-tests, openid-connect, pkce

What is the best way to login in Java based automated End-to-End API tests using the OAuth2 / OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow with PKCE?

Our company uses its custom IdP server, but we tried to follow the call documented at [OAuth0](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) assuming the calls and responses are standardised. (Is this assumption correct?)

The "GET code" call (Authorization) looks like this:

```
https://<company-idp-server-auth-url>?response_type=code&code_challenge=<Code Challenge>&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=<CLIENT ID>&redirect_uri=<URL-encoded REDIRECT URI>&scope=openid%20customer&state=<SOME STATE>&lang=en
```

According to the mentioned documentation we would expect a response like:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: YOUR_CALLBACK_URL?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&state=xyzABC123
```

From the response we could then extract the AUTHORIZATION_CODE value required by the next call (Token).

Before we get this response, however, we get redirected first to the "check_login" page and then to the "login" page, which returns an HTML form for login.

We tried to reverse engineer the required calls to send this form, but after a cryptic redirect we get further redirected to the login page again. We never get a response containing the AUTHORIZATION_CODE.

Is this really the only way to pass the credentials or is there an easier way to bypass this HTML form? Or is there even a good Java library for this task?

Answer (score 1):

OpenID Connect authentication workflows can involve multiple redirects, automated form posts and entry of multiple factors. Therefore only the start and end of the redirect are standardized HTTP requests.

**UI TESTS**

It is common to use tools such as [Selenium with Java](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-with-java-for-automated-test) to automate logins for test users and get credentials needed for API calls. This just involves actions such as button clicks and populating text controls. If 2FA is involved then this would typically be disabled for an automated test stage of your pipeline.

**API TESTS**

If instead your requirement is to get access tokens for test user accounts and call APIs, then one option when testing APIs is to mock the IdP infrastructure for an automated test stage of the pipeline, where the mock implementation achieves identical technical results.

This technique involves using a JWT library to issue mock access tokens that must be identical to the real ones, with the same JWT header values, scopes and claims. The only difference is that there is a different JSON Web Signature.

For an example, see [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mycompany/sample/tests/IntegrationTests.java), which uses Wiremock to simulate the IdP and return a JSON Web Keyset for testing. The API under test will use this so that its signature verification still works.

**SUMMARY**

So the answer depends on where you want to focus your test efforts. The first option is useful for proving that end to end apps work. The second option can be useful for testing each API in isolation.

Comment: We are writing API Tests, but for the End-to-End API Tests (using Java/ Cucumber) we need "real" access tokens, not moked ones.

Comment: I clarified my answer above. If you want to run a code flow for every backend test you could write Java code using an HTTP client, similar to this [bash script](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.tokenhandler.docker/blob/master/test/runHttpWorkflow.sh#L150) of mine. The client will have options to follow redirects, similar to curl's -L option, but actions such as posting passwords and auto form posts are tricky and require understanding of the vendor's implementation. Another option might be to use the older password grant to get user level tokens for test accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have users credentials.

The Authorize endpoints start the flow and redirect you to the login form, where your automated test will have to type a valid email/password of a registered user. Then, after a successful login, you'll get the AUTHORIZATION_CODE that can be exchanged server-side for a token that can call the userInfo endpoint.

Comment: We have the credentials of a test user, which we want to pass programmatically. The question is how? Do we have to go via the HTML form and resolve all these redirects (which currently doesn't work ; we con't get the AUTHORIZATION_CODE) or is there an easier way?

Comment: You need to go to the HTML form and programmatically add the credentials and click on submit. If everything goes well you will be redirected and will the AUTH_CODE